# Passing messages to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use [Alertify.js](https://alertifyjs.org) to display confirmation messages, etc. in my views. I've been struggling to find a good way to pass the message from controller to view.

I have a janky-feeling setup using TempData that works, but only if I'm returning a view, rather than a redirect, which is pretty useless.

I was initially going to add this capability to a base viewmodel, but `RedirectToAction` doesn't support passing viewmodels.

I either need to make the TempData stick around longer or use a different process entirely.

What I use now:

```
public class AlertifyMessages
{
    public List<AlertifyMessage> Messages { get; private set; } = new List<AlertifyMessage>();
    public void Add(AlertifyType type, string message, string callbackUrl = null)
    {
        Messages.Add(new AlertifyMessage(type, message, callbackUrl));
    }
}

public class AlertifyMessage
{
    public AlertifyType Type { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string CallbackUrl { get; set; }
    public AlertifyMessage(AlertifyType type, string message, string callbackUrl)
    {
        Type = type;
        Message = message;
        CallbackUrl = callbackUrl;
    }
}

public enum AlertifyType
{
    Log,
    Error,
    Success
}

/// <summary>
/// Applies Alertify messages to TempData after action method runs
/// <para>Can only be used with <see cref="BaseController"/></para>
/// </summary>
public class AlertifyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        BaseController bc = (BaseController)context.Controller;
        bc.TempData["Alertify"] = bc.AlertifyMessages;
    }
}

[Alertify]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController()
    {
        AlertifyMessages = new AlertifyMessages();
    }

    public AlertifyMessages AlertifyMessages { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        AlertifyMessages.Add(AlertifyType.Success, "Yay!", Url.Action("Index"));
        return View(/*new ViewModel()*/);
    }
}
// Then loop through and display messages in view using TempData
```

**Edit**
The accepted answer is correct, but to avoid tons of refactoring, I just added another filter to my attribute, below:

```
private const string alertify = "Alertify";
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    BaseController bc = (BaseController)context.Controller;
    bc.Messages = (bc.TempData[alertify] == null) ? new AlertifyMessages() : (AlertifyMessages)bc.TempData[alertify];
    // Faster? Better? Harder? Stronger?
    //bc.Messages = (AlertifyMessages)bc.TempData[alertify] ?? new AlertifyMessages();
}
```

Comment: TempData should work redirect. Why do think it is not working ? Can you share the code which is having isssue ?

Comment: @Shyju It works if I return a view, and doesn't if I return a redirect. I think the attribute is reassigning that tempdata entry, causing the existing one to be lost before it's ever given to a view. I just don't know how else to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current code the `OnResultExecuting` will be executed 2 times in the course of your redirect.

Let's say you are doing redirect like this,

```
public ActionResult Save(SomeViewModel model)
{
    AlertifyMessages.Add(AlertifyType.Success, "Yay!", Url.Action("Index"));
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Here when you return a result from the `Save` action method, it will executes the `OnResultExecuting` method of your AlertifyMessages filter whichs read the `AlertifyMessages` property value of the controller and set that to TempData.

Now since it is a redirect response, your browser will issue a new GET request to `Index` action, And for that action method also, it will execute the code inside `OnResultExecuting` and it will try to read the `AlertifyMessages` property and set that to `TempData`. But now your `AlertifyMessages` does not have any value because you did not set that in your `Index` action method. **Remember Http is stateless**. Index action method call here is like a totally new call and that call will create a new instance of the controller.

The solution is to reinitialize the `AlertifyMessages` property value. You can read it from the TempData

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    AlertifyMessages = TempData["Alertify"] as AlertifyMessages;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful to explain the redirected request is a new controller instance.